# Create dapps to display sensor output

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, dapps, dapp-development, raspberry-pi

i want to make a project that can integrate IoT and blockchain. So, can I use the blockchain to store the outputs from the sensors onto the Ethereum blockchain and create a dapps to display the sensor outputs that have been stored, in real time?
if possible, what about the fees for each transaction, will it be very high?

Comment: Do you really need to store the sensors data on-chain? Blockchains always have some kind of lag due to the block processing so it is unlikely it will work in real time.  You could process sensors data off-chain, and store fingerprints on the blockchain, so you will be able to validate them. Blockchains like ethereum weren't designed to store large amounts of data, so it will be quite expensive. You could use a layer 2 solution, but you will face similar problems.

Comment: you are right, I have tried using ethereum to store the DHT sensor output and it takes time to send the data into the blockchain. maybe you can give me a suggestion, what blockchain can be better than ethereum in storing data and low cost?

Comment: I don't think a blockchain will be useful for realtime data. Maybe you can create snapshot of the data and store fingerprints, any blockchain should be good for that.

Comment: hmm ok, thanks for the suggestion 